# ¿Como conseguir que Chrome reconozca font-family: Arial sin sarifa?(serif)

Tags: html, css

He intentado de diversas formas conseguir que mi CSS:

```css
.texto--big{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-style: arial;
}
.texto--small{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-style: arial;
}
```

Devuelva la fuente Arial, sin serif, en el navegador Google Chrome, sin embargo, no ha habido forma de conseguirlo, ni mediante html, o etiquetas CSS como `webkit`, por si hubiera problemas de compatibilidad.

Por si aún hubiera dudas:

[image: Arial sin serifa]

Necesito obtener la primera. Gracias.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El error, es que estas usando: `font-style: arial;` y la propiedad correcta es `font-family: arial;`. Mira:

```css
.texto--big{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: arial;
}
.texto--small{
    font-size: 25px;
    font-family: arial;
}
```

```html
<p class="texto--big">
  Texto grande
</p>
<p class="texto--small">
  Texto Pequeño
</p>
```

Comment: Tiene razón, qué fallo más tonto !

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ suele pasar